# How to remove Change-Id from git commit by command

Tags: git, gerrit

When I cherry-pick a patch from Gerrit and push it again to different branch on same server, the server reply error message:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To ssh://xxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/xxxx (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://xxxxxx.git'
```

Using `git commit --amend` to remove `Change-Id` line can fix this problem.

I want to write a script to do it automatically. Is there any command/parameter to achieve same result?

Comment: Note that removing the `Change-Id` (without letting the `commit-msg` hook add a new one) generally is a bad idea as it breaks Patch-Set tracking in Gerrit, meaning a new iteration of the commit would not be associated to the previous iteration. In general, Gerrit *does* allow to cherry-pick changes and push them for a new target branch (also see [this comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=117#c26)), so you should double-check the target branch you are pushing for.

Comment: Hi StephenKing, there are two branch A and B on the same server. I downloaded these branch using "repo init -u xxx.git -b <branch name>" where xxx.git is the same for both branch. I'm sure a patch in branch A is not exist in branch B. That's why I want to cherry-pick it and push to branch B.

Comment: I guess you meant me, not StephenKing. The question is whether in the `refs/for/xxxx (no new changes)` output the `xxxx` really matches your `B` and not `A`.

Comment: Hi sschuberth, I'm apologize for put the wrong name.

I wrote a small patch and try to push it to different branch without modify the default `Change-Id`. The error message show: 

`$ git push XXX HEAD:refs/for/BRANCH_A
...
To ssh://SERVER/PATH/linux-3.10.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/BRANCH_A

$ git push XXX HEAD:refs/for/BRANCH_B
...
To ssh://SERVER/PATH/linux-3.10.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/BRANCH_B (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://SERVER/PATH/linux-3.10.git'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `--no-commit` option; something like (you'll need to tweak this)

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit <sha-1>
COMMIT_MSG=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%s%b <sha-1>)
# some bash operation to remove the Change-id from COMMIT_MSG variable
git commit -m "$COMMIT_MSG"
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank  you. I use a similar way to push a commit to a different branch. I cherry pick a commit as normal, then remove the Change-Id line and amend the commit. 

`COMMIT_MSG=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%s%n%n%b HEAD | sed 's/Change-Id: .*$//g') && git commit --amend -m "$COMMIT_MSG" && git push xxxx HEAD:refs/for/xxxx`

Comment: Glad to have helped you. If my answer solved your problem, consider accepting it; this shows other people that this problem is solved.